# How do I handle collision detection in Scenekit with Swift?

Tags: swift, collision, detection, scenekit

I have been trying to set up a simple Scenekit scene with some physics so I could learn about how SCNPhysicsContactDelegate, categoryBitMask, collisionBitMask and the physicsWorld func work. Not sure if I need to set up a contactTestBitMask as well.

Learning about contact detection sent me down a long path of bitwise operators and the concept of bit masking. Adding in binary is fun!  However, this is all still very foggy and I am trying to cobble together several tutorials I've found in both SpriteKit and SceneKit.  [This is the most comprehensive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27372138/how-to-set-up-scenekit-collision-detection?rq=1) but it is in Obj-C and I don't understand it how to translate to Swift.

Here is what I have created. Any insights would be much appreciated. Can you see what I have set up incorrectly?  I would like to have a simple Print statement occur when the red rolling ball hits the blue target.  The floor, ramp and target are .static, while the rolling ball is .dynamic.

[image: Animated Gif of Scene]

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, SCNPhysicsContactDelegate {
    //category bit masks for ball node and target node
    // ball = 0001 -> 1 and target = 0010 ->2
    let collisionRollingBall: Int = 1 << 0
    let collsionTarget: Int = 1 << 1

//declare variables
var sceneView: SCNView!
var cameraNode: SCNNode!
var groundNode: SCNNode!
var lightNode: SCNNode!
var rampNode: SCNNode!
var rollingBallNode: SCNNode!
var targetNode: SCNNode!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //set up sceneview and scene. Define the physicsworld contact delegate as self
    sceneView = SCNView(frame: self.view.frame)
    sceneView.scene = SCNScene()
    sceneView.scene!.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(sceneView)

    //add floor
    let groundGeometry = SCNFloor()
    groundGeometry.reflectivity = 0
    let groundMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    groundMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.greenColor()
    groundGeometry.materials = [groundMaterial]
    groundNode = SCNNode(geometry: groundGeometry)

    //add ramp
    let rampGeometry = SCNBox(width: 4, height: 1, length: 18, chamferRadius: 0)
    rampNode = SCNNode(geometry: rampGeometry)
    rampNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 2.0, z: 1.0)
    rampNode.rotation = SCNVector4(1, 0, 0, 0.26)

    //add rolling ball
    let rollingBallGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.5)
    let sphereMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    sphereMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.redColor()
    rollingBallGeometry.materials = [sphereMaterial]
    rollingBallNode = SCNNode(geometry: rollingBallGeometry)
    rollingBallNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 6, -6)

    //add target box
    let targetBoxGeometry = SCNBox(width: 4, height: 1, length: 4, chamferRadius: 0)
    let targetMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    targetMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blueColor()
    targetBoxGeometry.materials = [targetMaterial]
    targetNode = SCNNode(geometry: targetBoxGeometry)
    targetNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0.5, z: 11.5)
    targetNode.rotation = SCNVector4(-1,0,0,0.592)

    //add a camera
    let camera = SCNCamera()
    self.cameraNode = SCNNode()
    self.cameraNode.camera = camera
    self.cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 13, y: 5, z: 12)
    let constraint = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: rampNode)
    self.cameraNode.constraints = [constraint]
    constraint.gimbalLockEnabled = true

    //add a light
    let spotLight = SCNLight()
    spotLight.type = SCNLightTypeSpot
    spotLight.castsShadow = true
    spotLight.spotInnerAngle = 70.0
    spotLight.spotOuterAngle = 90.0
    spotLight.zFar = 500
    lightNode = SCNNode()
    lightNode.light = spotLight
    lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 25, z: 25)
    lightNode.constraints = [constraint]

    //define physcis bodies
    let groundShape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: groundGeometry, options: nil)
    let groundBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .Static, shape: groundShape)
    groundNode.physicsBody = groundBody

    let rampShape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: rampGeometry, options: nil)
    let rampBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .Static, shape: rampShape)
    rampNode.physicsBody = rampBody

    let sphereShape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: rollingBallGeometry, options: nil)
    let sphereBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .Dynamic, shape: sphereShape)
    rollingBallNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = collisionRollingBall
    rollingBallNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = collsionTarget
    rollingBallNode.physicsBody = sphereBody

    let targetShape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: targetBoxGeometry, options: nil)
    let targetBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .Static, shape: targetShape)
    targetNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = collsionTarget
    targetNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = collisionRollingBall
    targetNode.physicsBody = targetBody

    //add nodes to view
    sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(groundNode)
    sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(rampNode)
    sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(rollingBallNode)
    sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(targetNode)
    sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(self.cameraNode)
    sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

}

func physicsWorld(world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBeginContact contact: SCNPhysicsContact) {
print("contact")

 //   let contactMask = contact.nodeA.categoryBitMask | 
//contact.nodeB.categoryBitMask

    //if contactMask == collsionTarget | collisionRollingBall {
      //  print("The ball hit the target")
  //  }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: **UPDATE:** I have managed to solve the problem.  I realized that the collisionBitMasks I set up for the different nodes in the scenes were incomplete. I defined a more complete list of collision interactions for the various nodes in the scene.    Also, I changed `contact.nodeA.categoryBitMask` to `contact.nodeA.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask` and everything worked.  Not sure why that made a difference but it did.  Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're having to reset the "catagoryBitMask" value in the delegate function because you're trying to set the "catagoryBitMask" and "collisionBitMask" values when the physicsBody is still nil.

```
rollingBallNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = collisionRollingBall
rollingBallNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = collsionTarget
rollingBallNode.physicsBody = sphereBody
```

Try putting that 3rd line 1st.